# multiple installation usb osx

Tags: macos, installation, multi-boot, osx-yosemite

I am trying to set up a usb drive with three different installers for OSX (Mountain Lion, Mavericks, and Yosemite) using the following guide as a reference:

http://www.tonymacx86.com/mac-software/89554-how-create-multi-os-usb-installer-macintosh-hardware.html

These will only be used on MacBook Pro and MacBook Air notebooks.

However, when I try to install any of the versions of OSX, it asks for my Apple ID and password and will not install from the USB but instead downloads a fresh copy from the Apple Store. And since I do not have any upgrades other than Yosemite on my account, it won't allow me to install them. Just Yosemite.

I am wondering if anyone has suggestions they can make on how to get this accomplished so that the installation comes from the DMG on the USB drive and not the Apple Store.

I have thoroughly searched Google for answers but nothing helpful seems to be turning up.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted to be migrated to Superuser.  IMO this looks like admin related responsibilities to me.

Comment: Personally I think the OP might get better response on on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ with similar questions such as [this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-mavericks-install-usb-flash-drive)